# EmberJS Execute JS after Render on all Views

Tags: jquery, view, ember.js, render

I'm trying to run this code:

```
var width = 0; 
$('.photos article').each(function(){ width = width + $(this).width();});
$('.photos').width(width);
```

After the views render and can't figure out how to do that, here's the code with all the views and content:

http://jsbin.com/okezum/6/edit

I want to run my code on all views, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be achieved by defining the `didInsertElement` hook on all your view's and after getting the DOM element's id you can execute what ever jQuery code you might need. Since you want this to be executed on 'all' your view's you could write a general view from which all the view's that need the code to be executed do extend from.

Example:

```
App.GeneralView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var width = 0; 
    $('.photos article').each(function(){ 
      width = width + $(this).width();
    });
    $('.photos').width(width);
  }
});

App.IndexView = App.GeneralView.extend();
...
```

Note if need to get the view's id you can access it with `this.get('elementId')`, I've also modified your jsbin, see [here](http://jsbin.com/ezunic/5/edit) for a working version.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I see, maks sense :D but do you know why `width` is returning `0` ? :s

Comment: just put a console log, and it returns the valid width: http://jsbin.com/ezunic/3/edit

Comment: Hmmm that I got here while I was applying your code, the children width to sum and get a total width that I couldn't get, it return `[]`. I'm trying to get the `article` width, from all of then to sum :s know?

Comment: can it be that `$(.photos article)` does not match what you need? looking at your templates, should it not rather be `$(section article)`

Comment: I've also edited my answer since I didn't realize you want the actual element you are looping over rather than the hole view.

Comment: sorry, it's `$('section article')`, I forgot to update the example to the classes I'm using here. And seems that with `$("#"+this.get('elementId')).find('.photos')` I could find the section but from that when I try a `.find('article')` I get a `[]`, like there's no article, but inspecting the elements I see all articles :s I'm a bit confuse now haha

Comment: hmm, can you try to update your jsbin? it will be easier to avoid getting confused either for me :)

Comment: Sure :D here: http://jsbin.com/ezaget/1/edit and thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: the last jsbin you provided doesn't seam to work correctly, it does not load the posts...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this:

```
App.GeneralView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        if (this.$().find(".post img").length > 0) {
            var WIDTH = 0, HEIGHT = $(window).height(), SIDEBAR_WIDTH =   $('#sidebar').outerWidth();
            this.$().find(".post").each(function(){
                WIDTH += parseInt($(this).find('img').attr('width'));
                $(this).find('img').height(HEIGHT - 80).removeAttr('width');
            });
            $('body').children('.ember-view').innerWidth(WIDTH);
        } else {
            Ember.run.next(this, function() {
                this.didInsertElement();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Dont know if it's the best approach, but works ;s